# Visual Studio Android Emulator - Send SMS

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

I need to send an SMS to my app that I am developing, but the Visual Studios emulator isn't listening on my localhost, so I can't use:

telnet localhost 5554

I don't want to switch to the standard Android emulator because I use Hyper-V for other things, and the standard Android Emulator requires me to disable Hyper-V in order to work.

Is there any way I can simulate SMS messages being received by the phone in the Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

Comment: Could you solve this? I am facing the same issue and I can not figure it out what is wrong.